# Is there a way to show download complete message after downloadhandler saves files in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog, shinyapps

I am building an app, from which user can csv download files, i am using download handler for downloading the csv files. Each time user downloads a file , a modal message will appear to let the user know if download is completed. The problem is even when the user not saving the file/or cancelling the download window, the modal box is appearing as "download completed", is there a way to make the modal box to respond only when the user successfully downloaded file?(i am assuming user can chose any directory)

attaching the sample code below
:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # Our dataset
  data <- mtcars
  
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(data, file)
      
      showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Download Complete",
      easyClose = TRUE,
      footer = NULL))
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is something to do with browser settings: whether to allow user to give a different file name when downloading.